# When should you use a dedicated App Pool over Default App Pool?

Tags: website, windows-server-2008, asp.net, iis-7

Within IIS 7 when should you use a dedicated app pool, over the Default App Pool - This is the question.

Below are some of my thoughts on the question.

Does it use more resources to have all your applications using their own dedicated app pool?

Would it be good practice, for example to have a dedicated app pool for applications/sites that need to access a SQL database, and then other sites/apps that aren't accessing secure data, just put them in Default App Pool?

Can each site/application have it's own Web.config file if they all run from the Default App Pool?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does use slightly more resources, but it wouldn't be that much more than extending the existing app pool - the overhead for creating a new app pool is not a lot.

App pools are really about isolation as it is possible to interact with other applications running in the same app pool, even if they are set up as different sites.

Each application/site can have it's own web.config file.

I have no idea on best practice, but I would advise putting every app/site you run in a separate app pool. If you ever have performance problems or an unstable app which crashes a pool, isolating them will mean other pools are not affected.

Comment: Thanks that the kind of to the point answer I was looking for